# ElasticSearch: post_filter or filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a similar situation explained here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html

Before I stumbled upon this article, I have been using filter instead of post_filter for this kind of scenario, and it produced output just like the post_filter.

My question is: Are they the same thing? If not, which one is the recommended and more efficient method to use and why?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as **search hits** are concerned, they are the same thing, i.e. the hits you get will be correctly filtered according to either your filter in a `filtered` query or the filter in your `post_filter`.

However, as far as **aggregations** are concerned, the end result will not be the same. The difference between both boils down to what document set the aggregations will be computed on.

If your filter is in a `filtered` query, then your aggregations will be computed on the document set selected by the query(ies) and the filter(s) in your `filtered` query, i.e. the same set of documents that you will get in the response.

If your filter is in a `post_filter`, then your aggregations will be computed on the document set selected by your various query(ies). Once aggregations have been computed on that document set, the latter is further filtered by the filter(s) in your `post_filter` before returning the matching documents.

To sum it up,

- a `filtered` query affects **both search results and aggregations**
- while a `post_filter` **only affects the search results but NOT the aggregations**

Comment: Since, `filtered` has been deprecated in ES 2.0. Are there any changes because of that?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey In ES 2.x (and onwards), simply replace the `filtered` query with the `bool/filter` query, and the rest still applies.

Answer (score 7):

Another important difference between `filter` and `post_filter` that wasn't mentioned in any of the answers: ***performance***.

TL;DR

**Don't use `post_filter` unless you actually need it for aggregations.**

From [The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html):

> **WARNING: Performance consideration**
>
> Use a *post_filter* *only* if you need to differentially filter search
>   results and aggregations. Sometimes people will use `post_filter` for
>   regular searches.
>
> Don’t do this! The nature of the `post_filter` means it runs *after*
>   the query, so any performance benefit of filtering (such as caches) is
>   lost completely.
>
> The `post_filter` should be used only in combination with
>   aggregations, and only when you need differential filtering.

Comment: It's possible that your comment is not actual any more. A link you provided refers version 2 of ElasticSearch. In current (version 7, may be even earlier) versions this warning doesn't appear

Answer (score 3):

In my tests , I could find filter is behaving exactly as post_filter. Both are only affecting the hits section ONLY.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying so hard to find a difference until I saw this post and switched gears to find [Issue: Rename filter param to search api "post_filter"](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4119Z) which confirmed that.